# Can I rely on the element's color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, browser, colors

I have lots of such a condition in my codes: *(conditions which are based on the element's color)*

```
if ( $(elmnt).css("color") == "rgb(134, 134, 134)" ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Recently I've heard:

> relying on the color's element is wrong. Because different browsers return different kind of color. Like:
>
> - `rgb (0,0,0)`
> - `#000000`
> - `black`

Is this ^ true? anyway, as I said, I have lots of conditions like above in my JS codes, and now I don't know what should I do. Any suggestion?

**Note:** Changing all those conditions in my codes seems like a nightmare. `:-(`

Comment: Do you that you use `rgb (0,0,0)`, `#000000` and `black` at `css` and `javascript`?

Comment: @guest271314 No, I always use only this kind of color in my CSS codes: `rgb (0,0,0)`.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this is true. There is a jquery plugin that convert to/from the different notations. Don't have it atm but I'll search for it

Comment: @MartinAJ _"No, I always use this kine of color in my CSS codes: `rgb (0,0,0)`"_ Does `$(elmnt).css("color")` return expected result?

Comment: Make <code>or ||</code> condition and put black and #000000. But it will take time if you have alot of it.

Comment: @guest271314 Yes , `$(elmnt).css("color")` returns `rgb (0,0,0)` .. but I've tested it just in *Chrome-49* and *FireFox-16* ... I mean I don't know will it work on other browsers or not as expected. *(that's actually my question)*

Comment: firefox is at at least version 47. Do you mean firefox 46? You could substitute using `window.getComputedStyle()` for `.css()`

Comment: @guest271314 not really .. I don't use firefox *(I usually use Chrome)* .. I just installed FF for a test. I mean I didn't download a new version of ff just for a test.

Comment: The answer is **no**, you should never rely on javascript returning a certain format when it comes to colors. In addition to the ones mentioned in the question, newer browsers can return RGBA, HSL and what not, and you have no idea what will happen in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this RGB color parser for JavaScript:

http://www.phpied.com/rgb-color-parser-in-javascript/

Example use (from site):

```
var color = new RGBColor('darkblue');
if (color.ok) { // 'ok' is true when the parsing was a success
    // alert channels
    alert(color.r + ', ' + color.g + ', ' + color.b);
    // alert HEX and RGB
    alert(color.toHex());
    alert(color.toRGB());
}
```

Comment: Ohw. This answer is cool. I was coding for almost two year and I haven't encountered this yet. Thanks for the knowledge. Cheers (+1)

Answer (score -1):

I would not be relying on any UI-based value, especially if it is an important project that you want to stay bug-free. Using CSS-values such as color also makes your application prone to errors in future, as your check might fail, if you introduce elements with certain properties which you are checking.

You would also be depending on the color, so if the color does not satisfy your needs after all and you need to change it, you would have to change the color checking code as well.

It is also true that there might be browser and especially JavaScript-library differences regarding how they return you the element's color attribute, so you if you decide to go with this color-checking way, you need to take these difference into account as well, which is not necessarily any faster than changing all the code you are currently afraid of having to rewrite.

Using the UI's state to check something, be it important or not, is also a bit foolish - think of the following scenario:

You are developing an online book store, where users can select books to their shopping baskets and then buy them. Before buying, users must fill their book store account balances by transferring some sum of money from their bank account to their book store account.

When checking out, there is a big "Check out" button, which is visible only if the user has enough money on their book store account, otherwise it is invisible.

Every time the button is pressed, it calls a function `getBooks()`, which redirects the user to a page that says "the books are on the way!" and informs you that someone has bought some books and you need to start packaging and posting the books.

Now, what is wrong here? Clearly the user is not able to press the button, if he/she does not have enough money on their book store account, as the button is invisible... But what if the user is a bit more clever than that, inspects the checkout page for a while and notices that he/she only needs to call the `getBooks()` function to get the books, regardless if he/she has money on his/her book store account, because you have only been relying on not showing the button if there is no money on the user's account.

This is a big problem an I don't actually know the official name for this type of programming failure, but it is called something like "UI blocking", "Action blocking with UI" or "Security through UI". It commonly happens with vendor NPCs in MMO games - you click a vendor and a window pops up, from where you can buy items, and all the buy buttons for items that you do not have money for are disabled and greyed out. Your in game money is not always checked on the server-side and therefore you can just buy all the items regardless if you have money or not, if you just know which buy button's function to call, since you cannot press the button itself.

Comment: Most of this doesn't really relate directly to the question. What is relevant would make a better comment than an answer

Comment: @DelightedD0D You might be right, I probably went a bit off-topic there. However, the question was if one can rely on elements color, which in my opinion, was answered and explained why relying on color or for other UI-based values is a bad idea.

Comment: A seemingly fair point. But you honestly don't cite any real information regarding the reliability of checking an element's color. You really just discuss why you beleive *"Using the UI's state to check something, be it important or not, is a bit foolish"*. which gives  us your opinion, but doesn't address the actual question.

Comment: @DelightedD0D Fair enough. On a side note, one of the reasons MVC-models exist is to specifically separate UI from the business logic of the application, to counter problems like this for example. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: True, but MVC is not a magic bullet. As a contrived example, consider if the OP had an app where the user were allowed to change the background color of a particular div. The OP may write a check that says "if the user changes the background color to black, automatically change the text color to white so the text is still visible". Clearly MVC would be a far way to go to solve such a trivial problem. Checking UI state in this case would make sense.

Comment: @DelightedD0D I would still probably do something like that by enumerating the user's choices and by having a predetermined text color for each choice, assuming that the choices are limited. If they are unlimited, then the user should be able to change the text color to what ever as well, or other option would be to use something like TinyColor (https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor) to dynamically calculate a complementary text color for the background color.